# HP Elite 8300 SFF - Recovery without Recovery Partition... where's my image?

Tags: windows-8, formatting, reinstall

I'm trying to re-image my machine... at the moment it doesn't have *ANY* os on it, as the drive has been wiped, thus any recovery images are gone, too.

This poses a problem when I'm reinstalling Windows: I am being prompted for a license key, which I don't have since it's stored in the BIOS (and no longer on the side of the box on a sticker).

Where can I find an image to install that will pull the license from the BIOS, OR, is there a way I can scrape the license out of the BIOS by, say, booting into a Windows PE, slackware, something else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call HP to order a media kit, as they no longer ship it with the PC. Be adviced they will charge you a small fee for that service.

It's your responsibility to burn the image to a dvd or to a usb key, and the app surelly told the same.

Comment: Thanks for this, and you're correct -- I was able to track down those disks. :)